# How do I move the folder to the new site build?

Tags: propel, file-transfer

How can I transfer the build folder to another site?

The problem is that the name of the database table prefix is sewn into the files and if I have a lot of sites I will have to manually change the data. Is it possible to automatically change the table names and prefixes?

For example:

```
abstract class BaseCategoriesPeer {

/** the default database name for this class */
const DATABASE_NAME = 'test';

/** the table name for this class */
const TABLE_NAME = 'test_123_categories';
```

For each new site I will have to change the data?

Comment: Can you write a better question? I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly, here's a possible solution:

You can check the **directory** in which your source file is, and make a `switch` to define a variable (let's say) `$appStored`.

Then in a class for database access definitions (it's more common than a table name schema that depends on the deploy site), you make another `switch`, this time `switch ($appStored)`, and then define the names for each deploy configuration.

Comment: Thanks! sorry my english ;) I'm doing a module and it can work on many sites, I will be hard to change every time the configuration file

Comment: You're welcome! So you still have questions ? What did you think about my suggestion ?